# Когда приложение не активна уведомление приходит без данных

Tags: уведомления, android-notification, push-уведомления, android-push-notification

Когда отправляю уведомление на не активное приложение оно приходит с title, body, image но без data.
А когда приложение активна приходит всё.

В чем причина?